# Rss Feeds - Weblog module - Sitecore 8.1 Update 2

Tags: rss, weblog

I have the Weblog module installed on my site. I am now on sitecore 8.1 Update 2.
Rss Feeds used to work well with old versions of sitecore. Not sure why it isn't working now.

I used the following site to validate my feed and it is giving me the following errors:

> 1- This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of
>   feed readers could be improved by implementing the following
>   recommendations. line 1, column 0: Avoid Namespace Prefix: a10 [help]
>
> 2- line 1, column 14721: Missing atom:link with rel="self" [help] ...
>   Nov 2014 14:30:02 -0600

Any idea where I can fix those errors in the RSS feed, or should I update something or write a specific class to overwrite the current one?

Your reply is kindly appreciated..
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WeBlog utilize standard RSS feed functionality delivered by Sitecore.

Take a look at the **RSS feed item** and its template: `/sitecore/templates/System/Feeds/RSS Feed`

**RSS Feed template** uses default **Feed Delivery Layout** (`/sitecore/layout/Layouts/System/Feed Delivery Layout`)

You can find it in your website root: `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Feeds/Layouts/FeedDeliveryLayout.aspx`

When you open it there is nothing special there:

```razor
<%@ Page Language="c#" Inherits="Sitecore.Syndication.Web.FeedDeliveryLayout, Sitecore.Kernel" CodePage="65001" %>
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">
```

If you feel you need to overwrite something this is the way to go.

You can write your own implementation of

```cs
Sitecore.Syndication.Web.FeedDeliveryLayout, Sitecore.Kernel
```

class and edit the **FeedDeliveryLayout.aspx** file or create your custom Layout with your own implementation which is more elegant.

**Edit:**

**TL;DR**: *I think you are using wrong validator*

Are you sure that content returned by **RSS Layout** is different than previously?

I don't think that anything changed in Sitecore code. I compared code of following classes, used to generate RSS (`8.1.0.0` vs `6.0.0.0`)

- `FeedDeliveryLayout.cs`
- `FeedManager.cs`

No changes.

I think that right now your are trying to validate your feed as **Atom feed**. ([**Atom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)) feed and [**RSS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed are different formats).

Sitecore code:

```cs
public static string Render(SyndicationFeed feed)
{
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) feed, "feed");
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer = (XmlWriter) new XmlTextWriter((TextWriter) stringWriter);
    feed.GetRss20Formatter().WriteTo(writer);
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

As you can see Sitecore use:

`GetRss20Formatter`

> **Rss20FeedFormatter Class**
>
> A class that serializes a SyndicationFeed instance to and from RSS 2.0 format.

Validation **warnings** are for Atom.

You can find out more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx#Examples

If you really want to switch to **Atom** format, then writing your own Feed Layout is the only one way

Comment: I saw that Weblog is using the functionality delivered by Sitecore, and it was working well before on previous versions in sitecore. I was wondering if something got updated on the RSS that made it not valid now.

Comment: Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: @joanelaydi I updated my answer with additional information.